# GMail diff algorithm for emails

Tags: algorithm, email, diff

When you send an email, normally the mail client "quotes" all of the old email.
But because this is done on the client-side, there of course is no standard in doing so:

- Some insert > at the beginning of a line as indicator of a quote
- Some write new text OVER the quoted text, some UNDER
- webOS for example does not have any means of "quoting" old text. It is just inserted as is.

GMail does a very good job at filtering out the old parts of already sent emails and offers the user the option "show quoted text".

Are there any similar algorithms out there to detect those similar parts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what algorithm gets used but since this is email and not code, diff sould be a lot easier. Basically if you treat each line as a char in a string (use some hash representation) then the email can be represented as a string (one char for each line).

Then you can use minimum edit distance algorithm to figureout what got added and what got deleted to get from one email to another. All the stuff that is common, becomes your quoted text, all the stuff that got added is your new email.

Here is a link to string [edit distance algo](http://tarunsays.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/minimum-edit-distance-levenshtein-distance/):